# In JPlayernot able to play flv file

Tags: jquery, jplayer

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer( {

      ready: function () {

        jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
          m4v: url, // Defines the m4v url
        }).jPlayer("play"); // Attempts to Auto-Play the media
      },
      volume: 0.5,
      wmode:"window",
      swfPath: "js/libs/plugins/jQuery.jPlayer.2.1.0/Jplayer.swf",
      supplied: "m4v",

    });
```

I am able to play all video except .flv  .Can anyone sugget me something based on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show an .flv. How have you configured "setMedia" and "supplied" to handle .flv files.

Is it possible for you to configure an error handler in jPlayer to determine the error reason:

```
error: function(e) {
  alert( e.jPlayer.error.type );
}
```

Comment: e_url is usually caused by a firewall or proxy problem. Can you watch .flv files on sites like YouTube?

Comment: is their any need to provide supplied and support argument

Comment: I supply both supplied and solution: `solution: "flash, html", supplied: "flv, m4v"`

Comment: Oh, and supply both flv and m4v files to setMedia

Comment: context: "assets/resources/video/ch1_LO1_slide_01.flv"
hint: "Check media URL is valid."
message: "Media URL could not be loaded."
type: "e_url"